# Populate one dropdown list based on the selection of other dropdown list using Spring Boot

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, frontend, thymeleaf, backend

I tried my best to find a solution for this but I couldn't, I am trying to make the user select a category name, and based on this selection it will load the product's properties that are associated with this category.

I can load the categories and the products but i can't load the products based on the categories and the product's price i need it to be displayed but the user can't change the price.

CartItem Controller:

```
  @Controller
public class CartItemsControllers {

    @Autowired
    private CartItemService shoppingCartService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public CartItemsControllers(CartItemService shoppingCartService, CustomerService customerService, ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
        this.customerService = customerService;
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    //Model

    @ModelAttribute("cartItem")
    public CartItem cartItem()
    {
        return new CartItem();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("product")
    public List<Products> initializeprodcuts(){
        List<Products> products = productRepository.findAll();
        return products ;
    }

    //create form
    @GetMapping("/cart/create")
    public String createCartItem(Model model)
    {
        CartItem cartItem = new CartItem();

        model.addAttribute("cartItem",cartItem);

        return "MakeABill";
    }

    //Save
    @PostMapping("/cart/save")
    public String saveCartItem(@ModelAttribute("cartItem") CartItem cartItem)
    {
        shoppingCartService.saveCart(cartItem);

        return "MakeABill";
    }


@GetMapping("/products/{categoryId}")
public List<Products> getCategoriesProducts(@PathVariable Long categoryId)
{
    return productRepository.findByCategoriesId(categoryId);
}
```

CartItem Entity:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="cart_items")
@AllArgsConstructor

public class CartItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long cart_item_id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    private int product_quantity;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "product_id")//this column is the foreign key
    private Set<Products> product = new HashSet<>();

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public CartItem()
    {

    }
```

Products Entity Class:

```
 public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long product_id;

    private String product_name;

    private double product_price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id") //the name of the column in the other class and that name will be a column in the class
    private Categories product_category;


    private String product_quantity;

    private String product_Section;

    private String product_ExpDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_item_id") //the name of the column in the other class and that name will be a column in the class
    private CartItem cartItem;
```

ProductRepository:

```
    @Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Long> {

    List<Products> findByCategoriesId(Long categoriesId);

}
```

Make A Bill HTML PAGE:

```
                    <form th:action="@{/cart/save}" method="post" th:object="${cartItem}">

                    <div class="row g-3">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h4 class="mb-3">Select A Product</h4>
                            <br>

                            <label th:for="category"> Category : </label>
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="category" autofocus th:change="getProducts()"> <!-- the name of the variable  -->
                                <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                <!-- ${product} this is the model attribute  -->
                                <!-- th:value="${product.categories_id}" value here is the id-->
                                <!-- th:text="${category.categoryName}" text is what i want to be shown that eqauls to the id-->
                                <!--<option th:each = "product: ${product}"
                                        th:value="${product.product_category.categories_id}"
                                        th:text="${product.product_category.categoryName}"

                                ></option>-->

                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <label th:for="product"> Product Name : </label>
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="product" autofocus>
                                <option value="">Select Product</option>
                                <option th:each = "product: ${product}"
                                        th:value="${product.product_name}"
                                        th:text="${product.product_name}"
                                >
                                </option>
                            </select>

                            <br>

                            <label th:for="product_price"> Product Price : </label>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="product_price"  th:value="${product_name}" th:text="${product_price}" disabled >


                            <br>
                            <label th:for="roles"> Product Quantity : </label>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="product_quantity"  th:field="*{product_quantity}" autofocus>

                            <br>


                            <button class="w-5 btn btn-primary " type="submit" id="add_submit">Add </button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
<script>

    function getProducts(){

   //get the category id
   var categoryId = $('#category').val();
    $.get("/products/" + categoryId, function(data){
        var option = "";
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            option += "<option value = " + value.id + ">" + value.product_name +  "</option>";
        });
        $("#product").find('option').remove().end().append(option);
    });
}
</script>
```

I got an error here:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cartItemsControllers' defined in file [E:\Spring Boot\warehouseManagementSystem\target\classes\com\example\warehouseManagementSystem\Controllers\CartItemsControllers.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingCartImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByCategoriesId(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByCategoriesId(java.lang.Long)! No property categoriesId found for type Products!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByCategoriesId(java.lang.Long)! No property categoriesId found for type Products!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
```

Comment: If I am not wrong you have raised multiple questions for similar issue. Any particular reason? Or they are different issues all together?

Comment: I solved others but that one still couldn't know how to do it but i am trying your solution, thanks so much for your help. i will update the question if i got any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can populate products depending on selected categories using jQuery like below

```
function getProducts(){
    
   //get the category id
   var categoryId = $('#category').val();
    $.get("/products/" + categoryId, function(data){
        var option = "";
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            option += "<option value = " + value.id + ">" + value.product_name +  "</option>";
        });
        $("#product").find('option').remove().end().append(option);
    });
}
```

Call getProducts() method using

```
<select id="category" th:change="getProducts()">
```

Define a Rest API endpoinnt `"/products/{categoryId}"` that returns list of products for given categoryId like below

**Edit 1**

```
@Controller
class CategoryController{

  @AutoWired
  private ProductRepository productRepository;

  @GetMapping("/products/{categoryId}")
  @ResponseBody
  public List<Products> listProducts(@PathVariable long categoryId){
    return this.productRepository.findByProduct_category(categoryId);
  }
}
```

Comment: sir, can you please help me, how can i create the Rest API endpoint. and i updated what i have done

Comment: Error is because of List<Products> findByCategoriesId(Long categoriesId); method declaration. You should be using property name available in Products entity. Try using List<Products> findByProduct_category(Long categoriesId); instead of findByCategoriesId() 

Updated answer with Rest API endpoint 

If possible, upload your code to git hub repository and share the link. Will go through it.